# Aptana Studio 3 - Generic server doesn't support start

Tags: php

I just updated Aptana today to Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.2.1.201207261642.
When I try to run any project an error window pops up with the message:

'Launching Google Chrome - Internal Server'  has encountered a problem.
Generic server doesn't support start.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to post that I already found the answer to my problem.

I had to go to Run->Run Configurations...->Server->Use Base URL: here, I put "http://localhost/".

Before the update, I used - Use Selected Servers, where I configured Wamp Server which caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, this problem is not solved - see also here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7571

It seem's like Aptana doesn't get the right URL (step 3):
1. Project Properties -> Preview settings
2. Use specific server -> new
3. Simple Web Server -> [fill in] Name, URL, document root

I'm using XAMPP and my index.php does work very fine by using my browser manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that issue just now.

Click the link below and find title tells "Using Your Server for Previews" then follow the orders.

[aptana studio 3 external server](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/aptana-studio-3-guided-tour-and-tutorial-create-a-web-project-using-the-html-5-boilerplate-framework.html#fbid=M5uN_ag1R-S)

Comment: can you not include the relevant info instead of forcing the user to hunt down on another page?

Answer (score 0):

1. run configurations...
2. for the individual browser exe file,
3. choose use selected web server and configure apche as a simple web server, choose the doc root that is correct, i called mine apache since that is what i have installed
4. then choose the "use base url" option. for me it was just "http://localhost"
5. now, i have "use base url" chosen, but apache is in the "use selected server" area BUT IT IS GREYED OUT.
6. all the answers on this drove me nuts. it just would not work. but this did work. before i did this it would try to see the php file in the browser from the "local" path, c:\program.... blah blah blah. and that won't work for a web server. i could browse it manually but that defeats the purpose.!
7. i had to do this for each browser that i want to use to preview with. which is all of them.
8. good luck. all the other posts on this sucked.

[this is a ss of what mine looked like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJBsP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.2.2.201208201020 
I have XAMPP my DocumentRoot:  C:/xampp/htdocs

To solve that  problem about, Generic server doesn't support start:

1. In the proyect click-right->properties
2. Click preview Settings
3. selecet new
4. !! Importantnt ! select:  External Web Server
5. name:  the name of the server.  anything
6. Base URL:  nos use localhost use la ip del localhost y el puerto 127.0.0.1:80
7. DocumentRoot: C:/xampp/htdocs
8. 

Try  whith any explorer;  if the problem still exist  then again edit the configuration and set the documentRoot using  the bowswer. it is all and ready